# Inline function ambiguity in Scala

Tags: scala, function

When passing an operator lifted to be a function to one of defined higher order functions, Scala allows for very concise syntax, e.g (please ignore the fact that it can be simplified to .product()):

```
List(1,2,3).fold(1)(_ * _)
```

To the above I can just pass `_ \* _`

However having defined my own toy function *zipWith()*, I need to be very explicit when passing a function:

```
implicit class EnrichedList[A](val self: List[A]) extends AnyVal {
  def zipWith[B, C](that: List[B])
                   (implicit zipper: A => B => C): List[C] = {

    def zipWithHelper(zipper: A => B => C)
                     (as: List[A])
                     (bs: List[B]): List[C] = {
      (as, bs) match {
        case (_, Nil) => Nil
        case (Nil, _) => Nil
        case (a :: restOfA, b :: restOfB) =>
          zipper(a)(b) :: zipWithHelper(zipper)(restOfA)(restOfB)
      }
    }

    zipWithHelper(zipper)(self)(that)
  }
}
```

This: `List(1, 3, 4).zipWith(List(3, 4, 5))(_ * _)` will not work, saying

> Error:(60, 46) missing parameter type for expanded function ((x$1: , x$2) => x$1.$times(x$2))
>   List(1, 3, 4).zipWith(List(3, 4, 5))(_ * _)

I need to say what type of arguments function takes:

```
List(1, 3, 4).zipWith(List(3, 4, 5))((x: Int) => (y: Int) => x * y)
```

Why won't the compiler allow me just to pass in a shorthand version `_ * _`?

Comment: Question is clear, solution attempt is there, error message is there, the solution is almost correct (up to currying), even formatting is nice, with inline code and quote-blocks for the error messages. How is this question worth a downvote O_o?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The expression `_ * _` is not shorthand for `(x: Int) => (y: Int) => x * y`. It's a shorthand for `(x: Int, y: Int) => x * y`. If you change the type of `zipper` to `(A, B) => C` instead of `A => B => C`, it should work. *Currying* is a thing, it's not just a fancy name for an identity function.

This here compiles:

```
implicit class EnrichedList[A](val self: List[A]) {
  def zipWith[B, C](that: List[B])
                   (implicit zipper: (A, B) => C): List[C] = {

    def zipWithHelper(zipper: (A, B) => C)
                     (as: List[A])
                     (bs: List[B]): List[C] = {
      (as, bs) match {
        case (_, Nil) => Nil
        case (Nil, _) => Nil
        case (a :: restOfA, b :: restOfB) =>
          zipper(a, b) :: zipWithHelper(zipper)(restOfA)(restOfB)
      }
    }

    zipWithHelper(zipper)(self)(that)
  }
}

println( List(1, 3, 4).zipWith(List(3, 4, 5))(_ * _) )
```

and prints

```
List(3, 12, 20)
```

Comment: Thanks for answering! Can't multiparameter functions be turned into curried functions though?

Comment: @user3681304 There is a method `.curried`. Example: `val f = (x: Int, y: Int) => x + y; f.curried`. But there is no underscore placeholder syntax for curried functions.